# Modifying .vb file in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, save, overwrite

I've never had any problems with building my solution after making changes to the .vb files in my project.
Now, each time changes are made to the .vb files in my project, an asterix (*) appears next to the filename in VS 2013.

When I try to build my application, a 'save as' dialog appears and when I try to click save, it says that it can't make a file that already exists.

The .Vb files are not set as 'read-only' files.
Why can't it just overwrite?

Comment: Try restarting your computer?  Maybe something is locking the files.

Comment: I just found out that I have the same problem with word documents.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, unfortunately.  Try on SuperUser?

Comment: Restarting my computer worked! thanks